# PHP - unable to create file with chrome but OK with IE

Tags: php, file, google-chrome, logging, easyphp

I am running **easyphp 14.1**.
I usually use **Chrome** to test end debug the application.
In my project, I have a logging class, which writes logs in a file. If the file doesn't exists, it is created.

Until now, everything worked perfectly, but today, logs are no longer written when using chrome.

- I checked folders permissions, everything look good.
- I tried to delete and recreate manually both the folder and the log file, but nothing worked.
- So I tried to open my project with IE, and I don't know why, logs started to work again.
- But with **Chrome**, it still doesn't work.

I don't understand the link between the browser used and the action to write logs in a file with PHP.

Can anyone help me to understand this weirdness ?

**EDIT : the source code**

```
<?php
class clLog{

    const erreur = "[ERROR]";
    const warn = "[WARNING]";
    const trace = "[TRACE]";

    /**
     * 
     * @param $dConfig: la config du fichier INI
     * @param $msg: le message à afficher
     * @param $level: niveau de trace
     * @return
     */
    public static function Debug($dConfig, $msg, $level=clLog::trace) {
        // Ecriture selon le level
        if($dConfig['log']['level'] > 1){
            $path = $dConfig['path']['racine'].$dConfig['log']['debug_path'];
            // Verifie l'existance du dossier de destination.
            if(is_dir($path)){
                // Instance de log afin d'utiliser la fonction d'écriture
                $o = new clLog();
                // Construit le message
                $message = date('H:i:s')." ".$level." ".$msg."\r\n";
                // Construit le path du fichier de log SQL d'aujourd'hui
                $file = $path.$dConfig['log']['debug_file']."_".date('d-m-Y').".log";
                // Ecriture dans fichier
                $o->Ecrire($file, $message);
            }
        }


    /**
    * action: ecrit le message $msg à suite du fichier dont l'url est passée en paramètre
    * paramètres:
    *   - url: adresse du fichier
    *   - msg: message à insérer
    *retour: aucun.
    */
    private function Ecrire($url, $msg)
    {
        $fp = fopen($url, 'a+');
        fwrite($fp, $msg);
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It shouldn't be because of browsers. Show your code so people can help you better.

Comment: Which logs? Console.logs? Did you deactivate javascript and forgot to activate it again in Chrome?

Comment: No, I'm talking about php logs, I write logs in a file with php, it should not have to do with browsers but in my case, there is a difference between using chrome and IE